# working with netCDF on python with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, netcdf, python-xarray, netcdf4

So I am pretty new in programming, currently doing some research on netCDF .nc files to work with python. I have the following code which I am sure it will not work. The objective here is to plot a graph simple line graph of 10m u-component of winds over time.
The problem I think is that 10m u-component of winds has 4D shape of (time=840, expver=2, latitude=19, longitude=27) while time being only (time=840).
Any replies or ideas will be much appreciated! The code is as shown:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

nc = Dataset(r'C:\WAIG\Python\ERA5_py01\Downloaded_nc_file/test_era5.nc','r')

for i in nc.variables:
    print(i)

lat = nc.variables['latitude'][:]
lon = nc.variables['longitude'][:]
time = nc.variables['time'][:]
u = nc.variables['u10'][:]


plt.plot(np.squeeze(u), np.squeeze(time))
plt.show()
```

Comment: So what's your question? What's wrong with the results of this code?

Comment: Suggest you use xarray.  Not clear what you want to plot given that your data is 4D.  What visualization are you after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, you have winds that represent the 10m wind at every location of the model grid (lat,lon) as well as dimensioned on `exper`--not sure what that last one is. You need to select a subset of u. For example, let's pick `exper=1`, and lat/lon indexes of `lat=8`, `lon=12` (not sure where those are going to be:

```
exper_index = 1
lat_index = 8
lon_index = 12
# ':' below means "full slice"--take everything along that dimension
plt.plot(u[:, exper_index, lat_index, lon_index], time)
plt.title(f'U at latitude {lat[lat_index]}, longitude {lon[lon_index]}')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `xarray`?

I think that it will be easier for you to read the `netCDF4` file and plot it using `matplotlib`.

This is straight forward:

```
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_dataset('C:\WAIG\Python\ERA5_py01\Downloaded_nc_file/test_era5.nc')
```

This line will plot the timeseries of the horizontal mean U10

```
ds['u10'].mean(['longitude','latitude']).plot()
```

You can also select by the value or index in a specific dimension using `sel` and `isel` methods:

This line selects the 10th latitude and 5th longitude and plot it. In this case I am interested in specific indexes for latitude and longitude, not in the real units.

```
ds['u10'].isel(latitude=10,longitude=5).plot()
```

This line selects the nearest value of latitude and longitude to the given values and plot it. In this case, I am interested in the values of latitude and longitude in the real units.

```
ds['u10'].sel(latitude=-15,longitude=40,method='nearest').plot()
```

See their [documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/visualization_gallery.html) to learn more about `xarray`.

I hope this solution is better for your case and it also introduce you this great tool. Please, let me know if you still need some help with this.